# Context free grammar syntax

Tags: context-free-grammar, lexical, context-free-language

I'm trying to clarify the following about context-free grammar:

If I've got the following,

```
S->T0T
```

If there are two possible values for T ie.

```
T-> 1T | 1
```

Do I have to use the same value when substituting both Ts, like so:

```
T0T becomes (1T)0(1T) => 1T01T
```

Or can I use different values for each T, like so:

```
TOT becomes (1T)0(1) => 1T01
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no relationship between the two `T`s. The restriction that they had to be the same would make the grammar not context-free, since the replacement of `T` in a context-free grammar is independent of the context. Hence "context-free".